# Doctrine Subquery in InnerJoin

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

i have functional query in MySql:

```
select t.won,e.etot, s.username,s.country,r.points,r.rank FROM sf_guard_user s 
INNER JOIN marks r ON r.user_id = s.id 
inner join (select t.user_id,count(t.user_id)as won from topper t group by t.user_id) t on t.user_id=s.id
inner join (select e.user_id,count(e.user_id)as etot from exams e group by e.user_id) e on e.user_id=s.id
ORDER BY r.rank asc
```

i wrote doctrine code in sfGuardUserTable Class:

```
$q= $this->createQuery('u');

        $wq =$q->createSubquery()
         ->select('t.user_id,count(t.user_id) won')
         ->from('Topper t')
         ->groupBy('t.user_id');

        $dq = $q->createSubquery()
         ->select('e.user_id,count(e.user_id) etot')
         ->from('Exams d')
         ->groupBy('d.user_id');

        $q->select(' t1.won, e1.dtot, u.username,u.country,r.points,r.rank')
         ->innerJoin ('u.Marks r ON r.user_id = u.id')
         ->innerJoin ('u.('.$wq->getDql().') t1 on t1.user_id=u.id')
         ->innerJoin ('u.'.$dq->getDql().' e1 on e1.user_id=u.id')
         ->orderBy('r.rank asc');

        //echo $q->getSql();
        return $q;
```

it is giving error Couldn't find class SELECT :( please help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why is it necessary to abstract the query like that? Just type it out like normal people.

Comment: U R DOIN' IT WRONG.
You do not need Doctrine for such queries (`$q->select(' t1.won, e1.dtot, u.username,u.country,r.points,r.rank')`).

Comment: @ tor Valamo : could you guide me how to write like normal. i mean this is the only way i know because i dun want to execute more then one queries for the same task.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i tried to execute my custom query directly by Doctrine Row Sql query option and its work :)
i loved to share it here :

```
$q = new Doctrine_RawSql();
        $q->select('{t.won}, {e.etot}, {s.username},{s.country},{r.marks},{r.ranks}');
        $q->from('sf_Guard_User s INNER JOIN marks r ON r.user_id = s.id inner join (select t.id,t.user_id,count(t.user_id)as won from topper t group by t.user_id) t on t.user_id=s.id inner join (select d.id,d.user_id,count(e.user_id)as etot from exams e group by e.user_id) e on e.user_id=s.id ORDER BY r.rank asc');
        $q->addComponent('s', 'sfGuardUser s');
        $q->addComponent('r', 's.Marks r');
        $q->addComponent('t', 's.Topper t');
        $q->addComponent('e', 's.Exams e');
        return $q;
```

for more help [read it](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_0/en/native-sql).

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is the best solution but it works for me too :).